# QGIS from SHP to TAB

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tab

I have a problem trying to convert a .shp file which I successfully save as from QGIS. Im in MapInfo trying to use universal translator to convert that shp file into TAB file but it keeps giving error as translation failed. Is there any solution or work around to my problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "Save as" from QGIS to save to Tab file, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks underdark. I did that too but map info tab file cannot be edited or cannot save another copy. the default symbols that were saved remain. I tried editing the tab file but cannot be edited.

Comment: What QGIS version do you have? Please update your QGIS version to the latest version of 2.14.7 LTR, as you can edit the tab file now. The old version of QGIS cannot edit Tab file, but with the new version you can.

Comment: I am currently using Version 2.6. Thank you so much. Will do that